# Annoying Qt issue resulted from an experiment with the inclusion of <stdio.h>

Tags: c++, qt, error-handling, compiler-errors

As I was playing around with Qt I decided to use stdio.h in order to test some things. But as soon as I had built the application it started giving me errors such as :

> \dir\ :16: error: C2248: 'QString::QString' : cannot access private
>   member declared in class 'QString'

Naturally, to rectify this issue I just removed the #include  and I thought it would work. It did not.

Even after a clean and a qmake the error persists and now my perfectly working code is rendered useless from a silly inclusion of `stdio.h`.

Comment: The problem is probably not related to your `#include <stdio.h>`, it just leaded to a recompilation of a code that was incorrect. What method do you call on `QString`?

Comment: Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that replicates the problem, and show it to us? Most likely the attempt to create a MCVE will help you find the problem.

Comment: I thought no point of giving the code as anything related to QString leads to the said problem. 

ui->label->setText("Hello Some programmer dude"); //is an example that would lead to the same error

Comment: I even rebooted my PC, just to see if it would work as a lazy fix, but it did not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***enormous sigh fueled by relief and self-disappointment***

Just manually create a new kit and the issue would fix itself. If you have more than one kits, I think changing between them would fix it too.